# Cannot delete Azure sync agent

Tags: azure

I have problem with deleting Sync Agent in Azure.
My approach was trying to delete first Sync Agent on on-premise DB and then in Azure. However when I tried delete it, it failed with error ”Please enter a valid agent key to proceed. The key must be generated from SQL Data Sync web portal” For solution I tried (duo to help from stack) set same timezone on Azure and on on-premise DB, but without success.

Any advice please?
Thanks